# CentOS server unusable after interrupted dnf update

Tags: centos, dnf

I was running a `dnf update` on a CentOS 8 machine and it was stuck, so I killed the process after half an hour or so. Now nothing seems to work, even `sudo` is inaccessible. I've power-cycled the server, but still none of these basic commands work.

Running `dnf update` again shows name resolution errors:

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  — Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock
[Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org: Unknown error]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream':
Cannot prepare internal mirror list: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host
name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org/release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock
[Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error]
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Sounds like some core package was interrupted mid-update. It should be *technically* possible to recover from this, but it will be a more effective use of your time to either reload from backups or reinstall.

Comment: Shucks this is scary. We may not have recent backups. How can we recover from this -- by "reinstall" do you mean reinstall the whole CentOS?

Comment: That's correct. It's also a bit timely since CentOS was dropped from support and you'll be left without even the ability to download packages for it in the future. Give me a moment to write something here..

Comment: Who/what dropped CentOS support..DNF? What does this mean, we need to use YUM on CentOS now?

Comment: CentOS as a project is being dumped by Red Hat. https://thenewstack.io/red-hat-deprecates-linux-centos-in-favor-of-a-streaming-edition/

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. This is sad. Perhaps time to move to Fedora or FreeBSD. Off topic here, but coming from a CentOS world, which next OS of this variety would you recommend? I'm so impressed with your meticulous help (and knowledge) -- would value your direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yes, your system is in an inconsistent state. In the future, if `dnf` freezes up, try switching to another terminal and watching your system logs. Interrupting it with a hard power off is ***always*** a bad idea. In the worst case you can issue a `kill` and then try the transaction again.

There are a few things you can try here, but *please* back up this system before continuing. If none of these options work, you're likely to be left in an even more broken condition than before. Figuring out exactly what is broken and how is more art than science, especially since every breakage will be different.

1. The *fastest and least error-prone* thing you could do is to get all essential data off and do a complete reinstall. Please determine if it is a good use of your time to possibly troubleshoot this.
2. Become root.
3. Get a list of all duplicate packages on this system. `dnf repoquery --quiet --duplicated --cacheonly --latest-limit 1 --qf "%{name}.%{arch}" > dupepackages.list`
4. Try removing any duplicate packages. Run `dnf remove $(dnf repoquery --duplicated --cacheonly --latest-limit -1 -q)` as root. This will remove all but the most recent version of every package on your system. You may get a "protected package" error here, if so, re-run the command with the `--disableplugin=protected_packages`. This is the scary bit.
5. Now try reinstalling the dupes - this will upgrade everything to the newer version that was attempting to be installed before `dnf` was interrupted. `dnf reinstall -C $(cat dupepackages.list)` (I'd be willing to bet your dnf starts behaving correctly at this point)
6. If that worked, *immediately* re-run the upgrade that started this whole mess. With the dupes gone, `dnf` and `rpm` dependency resolution should kick in and return you to a stable state.

Comment: thank you for this. Before we do the whole reinstall etc, it would help us immensely to see if we can do the dnf fix. Running the dnf command in #3 still gives us the `Failed to download metadata for repo ApStream`

Comment: Actually I had done a `kill -9 {pid}` for the dnf update process from a different SSH terminal window, not a reboot.

Comment: @PKHunter append the `-C` or `--cacheonly` option to those `dnf` commands - those will instruct it to use the system cache instead of trying to update from the internet.

Comment: @PKHunter I see you accepted the answer - did this work for you?

Comment: Thank you @karu. I think this was very informative and helpful, hence the accepted. The commands aren't eventually worth the time as they result in a massive list of packages...the remove is in the thousands! And at the end of it there's the suggestion of using  `--skip-broken` or `--nobest`. I might just chuck this server, as you suggested.